# Vs code is there a way to access the objects defined in a script in the interactive window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, running a Python script or Notebook, is there a way to share the same objects in the interactive window?

For example, script1.py

```
x = 10
```

And after opening an interactive window in the same kernel.

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your python file from the terminal using:

`python -i script1.py`

This will give you access to inspect interactively after running script and your variables you have defined in your script1.py will be available in the interactive window.